# iphone view-based app

Tags: iphone

I've created a view based application and have connected all of my buttons through Interface Builder (and saved)...however upon launch all I have is a white screen on the simulator.

I've uncommented the viewDidLoad, and my header file has IBOutlet UIlabels defined.

I'm kind of baffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app delegate needs to have something like this in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
MainController *mainController = [[MainController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainController" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview:mainController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: If he used the view based template, this should be set up already.

Answer (score 1):

It might sound a bit stupid, but you should save your xib through interface builder.
Building and Running through xcode does not automatically save your xib.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't have that issue but I appreciate the reminder.